# Firebase keeps syncing three-way binded object when logged out

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I sync a list of friends for `$uid` (defined as `userId` in my code) using the three-way data binding method of Firebase.

I noticed that when on the same computer (I test in the same browser) I logout and then login with another email, then Firebase keeps syncing the data from the previous `userId`

So if I first login and my `userId = "userId_1"` and then logout, login with another email and my `userId = "userId_2"`, in my friendsList I get a three-way data binded list of friends from the refs:

```
fbREF + "/friends/" + "userId_1"
```

and

```
fbREF + "/friends/" + "userId_2"
```

How can I stop syncing the data from old userId?

---

**Method**

In my factory, I sync as follows:

```
    self.syncFriends = function(userId) {
        var ref = new Firebase(fbREF + "/friends/" + userId);
        return $firebaseObject(ref);
    };
```

where `fbREF = "https://CUSTOMREF.firebaseio.com"`;

When the user is logged in, obviously he has an userId retrieved by the function `ref.onAuth(fnCallback)`, which I call as follows:

```
self.checkSocialAuthState = function() {
      var qCheck = $q.defer();

      // --
      function authDataCallback(authData) {
        if (authData) {
          qCheck.resolve(authData);
        } else {
          qCheck.reject("SOCIALAUTH_LOGGED_OUT")
          console.log("User is logged out");
        }
      };

      // --
      var ref = new Firebase(fbREF);
      ref.onAuth(authDataCallback);

      return qCheck.promise;
    };
```

Then the `userId` is embedded in `authData["auth"].uid`.

Comment: I don't user angularFire, but how are you login the user out? Are you using `$unauth()`? https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-unauth

Comment: Uhm I use ref.unauth() and not with $ Should that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you execute unauth() method connection is active at firebase end. Hence please execute unauth() on logout. It should resolve your problem.